# Binding a List<string> to a Listview in asp.net 3.5

Tags: .net, asp.net, listview, asp.net-3.5

How do I bind a List to a  in ASP.NET 3.5

```
  <asp:ListView ID="lvDiagnosisCodes" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <ul>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </ul>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <%# Eval("Name") %>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
```

I am not too sure what do use in the Eval part. Since this is a generic List of string , there is no column name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19):

Don't use Eval. Bind it directly:

```
<%# Container.DataItem %>
```

Comment: weird, it works in my code. Are you sure the strings in the list are not empty?

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is create an anonymous object and set it to the Datasource property of your  Listview.

So if you have a list or an array of strings, do the following:

```
Dim myListOfStuff() As String = Manager.FetchMyStuff()

Me.lvDiagnosisCodes.DataSource = (From s In myListOfStuff Select New With {.Name = s}).ToArray
Me.lvDiagnosisCodes.DataSource.DataBind()
```

This way, you can use `<%# Eval("Name") %>` in the front end and bind to a "property"